# Analog of bash "echo $(cat file)" in python (one more time string interpolation)

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

I have a file values.txt with hierarchical formatting like this:

```
group1
      subgroup1
            value1
            value2
group2
      subgroup2
            value3
            value4
```

if in bash i execute

```
echo $(cat values.txt)
```

I will get the output:

```
group1 subgroup1 value1 value2 group2 subgroup2 value3 value4
```

I would like to get this string formatted the same exact way from inside the python script, so it will be very easy to split it by whitespace for further processing.

Thanks!

Comment: You can already split the file on whitespace `[\t\n\r ]+` to get a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Byron points out, `split` splits on whitespace by default, so you should be able to do just

```
contents = open("values.txt", "r").read().split()
```

and have the list you want, combining the two steps you described.  If you have some other use for the intermediate "string formatted the exact same way", you can produce it from the split list with

```
" ".join(contents)
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting - when i do split(" ") on such file i'm getting a lot of garbage in resulting list (new lines and empty elements), while split() that has to be default and supposedly uses whitespace as well is doing much better job. Thanks!

Comment: @Eugene, Whitespace isn't just spaces. Whitespace includes spaces, tabs, newlines and carriage returns. When you just use `" "`  you are splitting on a single space.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('values.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = ' '.join(data.split())
    print data
    # or just:
    data = file.read().split()
```

Comment: appreciate your help. Thanks!